# In Star Trek Deep Space 9, How did Benjamin Sisko see his dead wife again?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

I remember seeing an episode where he was sitting and talking to his dead wife.  How could that have happened?

Comment: She turned up in DS9 Emissary. Her image was used by an alien to speak to him. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Or do you mean Mirror Jennifer? http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Jennifer_Sisko_(mirror)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you referring to [DS9: Emissary](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Emissary_(episode))? The Jennifer you see in the episode is an alien using her image to communicate with Ben Sisko.

or [DS9: Through the Looking Glass](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Through_the_Looking_Glass_(episode)), where Ben encounters the Jennifer from the mirror universe.

Comment: It's probably Mirror Jennifer. They have a few "sit-down" conversations.

Comment: I think the one I had seen was from Emissary Time is Linear Part 2